# Closed-form equation for $\int_{0.5}^{1} Beta(\alpha,\beta)$?

Tags: beta-distribution

I don't know if this question is too trivial for you guys, it is not for me though...

Is there a closed-form equation for $b = \int_{0.5}^{1} Beta(\alpha,\beta)$?

$$
Beta = \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)}
$$
$$
B(\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}
$$

Google search doesn't help much when querying for a mathematical equation, I really tried...

Comment: What are you integrating, the density or the distribution, or something else? Note that the integral of the density is the regularized [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) which is not generally in closed form but might be doable in particular instances.

Comment: The PDF (Probability density function)

Comment: please edit the density into your question. What do you need this in closed form for? (It's easy enough to evaluate in practice). Do you really need the general case?

Comment: It is rather sloppy to omit the differential in this case. Which variable are you concerned with?

Answer (score 1):

There is ... but it is complicated, and not sure if that useful. I am assuming the integral you want is
$$
\int_{0.5}^1 \text{beta}(x; \alpha, \beta) \; dx
$$ where the beta density is $\text{beta}(x; \alpha,\beta)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)}$.

With some help from maple this integral is evaluated as
$$ 
{\frac {1}{{\rm B} \left(\alpha,\beta\right)\alpha} \left( -
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(\alpha,-\beta+1;\,1+\alpha;\,{\frac{1}{2}})}{2}^{-
\alpha}+{\frac {\Gamma \left( 1+\alpha \right) \Gamma \left( \beta
 \right) }{\Gamma \left( \alpha+\beta \right) }} \right) }
$$

Comment: Doesn't this just reformulate the question?  How would one go about computing values of $_2F_1$ accurately?  (It's not simple to do so in full generality.)

Comment: Maybe --- depends on what is the purpose of the question

Comment: Anyone who does not conceive of an regularized complete Beta function as a "closed form" is *a fortiori* not going to accept an algebraic combination of Gamma and hypergeometric values as closed!

Comment: Yes, that is *not* closed form in any sense I have seen the term used.