# Efficiently Computing The Beta CDF

Tags: python, cumulative-distribution-function, beta-distribution, numpy

I am using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) to JIT compile some looped python functions as part of a larger application. Ideally, everything will run in numba's "no python" mode, such that the loop can be parallelised.

One of these functions involves use of the Beta distribution CDF (the [regularised incomplete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedBetaFunction.html)):

$$I_z(z| \alpha, \beta) = \frac{B(z | \alpha, \beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)}$$

where

$$B(\alpha, \beta) =\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}$$

and

$$B(z|\alpha, \beta) = \int_0^{z} u ^{\alpha -1} (1 -u)^{\beta-1} du$$

To run in nopython mode, I would like to implement the above using **only** functions from python's standard math library and numpy.

Implementing $B(\alpha, \beta)$ is no problem as I can use `math.gamma` from the python standard library.

The problem is how to evaluate the integral for $B(z|\alpha, \beta)$, which -- based on my admittedly limited knowledge of the problem -- must be performed numerically.

Is there a "standard" way that this is implemented inside most statistical libraries, eg. scipy? [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218016/closed-form-equation-for-int-0-51-beta-alpha-beta) appears to ask a similar question but remains unanswered.

Please note that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ could be varied quite substantially, so a lookup table with interpolation is not an option.

**Solution for those searching for similar:**
I ended up following [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/394983/919) linked answer from the comment below by *whuber*. Doing some further reading lead me to [this implementation](https://github.com/codeplea/incbeta) on Github, along with [the author's explanation of the algorithm](https://codeplea.com/incomplete-beta-function-c).

Comment: I recently posted an efficient, accurate, well-tested implementation of this incomplete Beta function at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/394983/919.  It is arguably the "standard" way you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do numeric integration, you just need to setup the resolution. One way is to use naive implementation:

```
v = np.linspace(0,z,1000)
dv = v[1]-v[0]
np.sum(v**(a-1) * (1-v)**(b-1) * dv)
```

which gives `0.055928172212507204` when `z=0.5,a=3,b=0.4` for example.

Or, use `numpy.trapz`, a slighly more accurate way of integration due to using trapezoids, instead of rectangles (which gives `0.05583334509998778`):

```
np.trapz(v**(a-1) * (1-v)**(b-1), v)
```

and you can compare them with `scipy.integrate`:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
integrate.quad(lambda x: x**(a-1) * (1-x)**(b-1), 0, z)[0]
```

which gives `0.055833303967108956`.

Comment: Numerical integration will work fine for large parameters (albeit inefficiently), but if either one of them is less than $1,$ it may fail badly because of the singularity of the density near $0$ or $1.$

Comment: @whuber, I’m not surprised that my pragmatic engineering approach is different than a true statistician :)

Comment: I learned my numerical computing skills by making mistakes.  You remember those!  I spent a few weeks one summer debugging intricate code only to discover that I had been just a little sloppy in my implementation of a Bessel function, and propagation of a small numerical error in a few special cases was ruining everything.  It was a good lesson.